# How to convert dynamoDB BatchSave API failed batch results to list of pojos?

Tags: java, amazon-dynamodb

How to convert dynamoDB BatchSave API failed batch results to list of pojos? The dynamoDB BatchSave API failed batch results are represented in DDB low level API classes like PutRequest/DeleteRequest/WriteRequest/Map.

Is there a simple way to convert Map to pojo which represents a DDB table item?

It took hours to find a solution. Hence I would like to create a question and provide answer to save others time if they come across similar use case.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
private List<T> getFailedBatchListItems(final FailedBatch failedBatch, final Class<T> clazz) {
    return failedBatch.getUnprocessedItems()
                      .values()
                      .stream()
                      .flatMap(List::stream)
                      .map(WriteRequest::getPutRequest)
                      .map(PutRequest::getItem)
                      .map(e -> dynamoDBMapper.marshallIntoObject(clazz, e))
                      .collect(toList());
}
```